# Connecting usb peripheral to android device

Tags: android, usb-otg

I have a tablet device, OTG cable and one other USB device. This other device is connected to tablet over OTG cable. 
How to connect tablet to PC for debugging in the same time with this other USB device? I've tried over USB hub but then I can't see tablet from Eclipse. If I connect directly tablet to PC with cable for charging and data transfer than debugging works but than can't see that USB device that I have to connect and read some data from it. What to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use adb over TCP, the Android developer site has a short article [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/#debug-considerations) under Debugging considerations (bottom of the page).

Comment: Thanks guys. It works!!!! I didn't know that is possible debug over wifi. For other who has struggled with the same problem I found great guideline for solving this: http://stuffandtech.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-quick-tip-adb-over-wifi.html